# RestKit/RKObjectMapping: How do I add additional properties after data has been loaded from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I'm creating an iOS app in which I load some data from a web server with RestKit.

It's based on [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout).

The data I'm loading has the following structure (Only 1 item shown for brevity):

```
{ 
    "userID": "las404",
    "items": [{
        "id":"2000123",
        "startTime":"2013-09-05T12:00:00",
        "endTime":"2013-09-05T15:00:00",
        "title":"Title",
        "location":"Location",
        "description":"Description"
    }]  
}
```

And this is the `AttributeMapping` I use:

```
RKEntityMapping *eventMapping = [[RKEntityMapping alloc] initWithEntity:entity];
    [eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"title" ]];
    [eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
            @"id" : @"id",
            @"startTime" : @"start",
            @"endTime" : @"end",
            @"location" : @"location",
            @"classID": @"classID"
}];
```

And what I'd like to do is to add 2 properties to each of the Core Data/SQLite records; `week` and `userID` once the data has been loaded, but *before* it's added to the local DB.

But I think it'll unnecessarily "bloat" my JSON response, if I include this on *every* item (about 200). So can it be done? Perhaps in `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath...`?

**I'm a complete novice when it comes to iOS/Obj-C development** so any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Also: I've tried looking at the [RestKit documentation](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.3/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html) but I'm afraid I don't understand most of it)

Comment: Week is calculated from the start / end time?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you shouldn't add the data repeatedly to your JSON, you also shouldn't map it repeatedly into your destination objects. You should create a `User` entity and give it a relationship to your `Item` entity.

In this case you only have one response descriptor, and its mapping includes another mapping to process the nested data into the relationship.

For the `week` attribute of your `Item` entity, this should be a derived attribute that is updated in `willSave` on your managed object subclass (or a similar approach for derived attribute updates).